# Cleaning up/Uniformize bibliography for long document

Tags: writing, citations, latex, bibtex

I was wondering whether existed some software that would take as input a text file bibliography (for instance a bib file if you use bibtex), and that run it through google scholar (or any other database), so that it can return a uniformized bibliography.

As an example, suppose you have two items from the same conference

```
@inproceedings{mpi,
   author       = {Surname1 Name1 and Surname2 Name2},
   title        = {Some nice work},
   booktitle    = {Editor of the Name of Conference},
   year         = {2004},
 }
```

and

```
@inproceedings{RRnrj,
  author        = {Name3 S. and Name4 S.},
  title         = {Some nice work},
  booktitle     = {Name of Conference (Acronym)},
  year          = {2020},
  publisher     = {Editor},
}
```

and you would want it to return:

```
@inproceedings{mpi,
   author       = {Surname1 Name1 and Surname2 Name2},
   title        = {Some nice work},
   booktitle    = {Name of Conference (Acronym)},
   year         = {2004},
   publisher    = {Editor},
 }
```

and

```
@inproceedings{RRnrj,
  author        = {Surname3 Name3 and Surname4 Name4},
  title         = {Some nice work},
  booktitle     = {Name of Conference (Acronym)},
  year          = {2020},
  publisher     = {Editor},
}
```

(or whatever is the norm on the database).

Comment: Related question: "[What are good sites to find citations in BibTex format?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-are-good-sites-to-find-citations-in-bibtex-format)" over at TeX.SE.

Comment: I don't think that there exists software to reliably correct these kinds of errors in your bibliography -- especially given that the bibtex data available from publishers sometimes even contains errors.

Comment: Not aware of anything to "uniformize" in that way, and I don't think that running through Scholar would help - IME that and other databases have that sort of inconsistency in anyway. I fear that it's a hand-pruning task...

Answer (score 2):

If you have the DOI codes, the best thing is to use the API and get the references yourself:

```
curl -LH "Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex" http://dx.doi.org/[DOI code]
```

If you have them (and you should, for any modern article), parsing the bib to get them and getting the data can be done in a very simple script.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for would be a [reference manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software). There are a number of commercial and free software available, many of which also support BibTeX files. I'm not sure what you mean precisely by "uniformized," but I take that to mean that some style guide was applied to them (since only the "Publisher" field was added to reference "mpi" in your desired output). Many of those software programs will also allow you to choose a particular style of citation, and export the references to a BibTex file again.

Comment: The book title was also changed in ref mpi, the authors names were completed in ref RRnrj.

Comment: You may need to change some of these details manually, but these reference managers can pull as much by automatically looking up the DOI, arXiv or sometimes ISBN number. Import references, semi-automatic update then export them.